# How to disable ajax on jFormer

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

How can I disable ajax when submit form on jFormer? I just need a submit a form to another php file /not using ajax/.

**EDITED:**

[jFormer](http://www.jformer.com/documentation/)

Code:

```
    // create the form
    $loginForm = new JFormer("loginForm", array('submitButtonText' => 'Sign In', 'action'=>'login_check.php'));

    // Create the form page
    $jFormPage = new JFormPage($loginForm->id.'Page', array('title'=>'<p>Sign In</p>'));

    // create the form section
    $jFormSection = new JFormSection($loginForm->id.'Section');
    $jFormSection->addJFormComponentArray(
        array(
            new JFormComponentSingleLineText("username", "Username:", array(
                'validationOptions'=>array('required', 'username')
                , 'tip' => '<p>Type your <b>username</b>.</p>'
            ))

            , new JFormComponentSingleLineText("password", "Password:", array(
                'type' => 'password'
                , 'validationOptions'=>array('required', 'password')
                , 'tip'=>'<p>Type your <b>password</b>.</p>'
            ))

            , new JFormComponentMultipleChoice('rememberMe', '',
            array(
                array('value' => 'remember', 'label' => 'Keep me logged in on this computer')
            )
                , array('tip' => '<p>If a cookie is set you can have this checked by default.</p>')
        )
        )
    );

    // Add the section to the page
    $jFormPage->addJFormSection($jFormSection);

    // Add the page to the form
    $loginForm->addJFormPage($jFormPage);

    // Set the function for a successful form submission
    function onSubmit($formValues) {
        $formValues = $formValues->loginFormPage->loginFormSection;
        if($formValues->username == 'admin' && $formValues->password == '12345') {
            if(!empty($formValues->rememberMe)) {
                $response = array('successPageHtml' => '<p>Login Successful</p><p>We\'ll keep you logged in on this computer.</p>');
            } else {
                $response = array('successPageHtml' => '<p>Login Successful</p><p>We won\'t keep you logged in on this computer.</p>');
            }
        } else {
            $response = array('failureNoticeHtml' => 'Invalid username or password.', 'failureJs' => "$('#password').val('').focus();");
        }
        return $response;
    }
    $loginForm->processRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Unbind() may be what you need

```
$('#myForm').unbind('submit');
```

<strike>Mebbe simple as:</strike>

```
$('#myForm input[type=submit]').click(function(){
   return false;
});
```

I can't get it to work in jsfiddle, probably because of the php file it needs.

Comment: This will cancel the click functionality of the submit button, not allow the form to submit to another page without calling it through AJAX. The submit event handler would need to be manipulated to allow for it to continue with default instead of e.preventDefault(). https://github.com/kirkouimet/jformer/blob/master/source/development/scripts/JFormer.js#L483

Comment: I'm thinking you could probably unbind here: https://github.com/kirkouimet/jformer/blob/master/source/development/scripts/JFormer.js#L55 I don't know, I haven't checked or worked with jFormer before.